# How to make an opened link show that it is selected

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and I want my navbar buttons to show when selected. I added a hover function that works but I want it to remain like that when the link is opened. Here is what I have right now.

HTML:

```
...<body>
<header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo-text">
            <h1 class="text-logo">Title</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -3.7%;
 }
 ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 0%;
 font-size: 170%;
 }

 ul li a {
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 5px 40px;
 border: 2px solid #000000;
 font-weight: 700;
 }

 ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 }

 ul li a:visited {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
 }
```

What can I add or improve? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ```ul li a:active```

Comment: @demkovych still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an active class and use it in your pages accordingly

```
ul li a:hover,
.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

<li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -3.7%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0%;
  font-size: 170%;
}

ul li a {
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 5px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul li a:hover,
.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul li a:visited {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo-text">
      <h1 class="text-logo">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a new class and call it something like `.currentPage`. Now on each of your pages, you have to give the current li item the class currentPage.

For example, on index.html the first li needs the class.

Then customize that class.

There's no selector that is able to select your current page.